# R: Loops, Loop within a function

Tags: r

I have a vector `vector<-cumprod(c(11151, rep(1.01,100)))`. I want to insert this vector in the function:

```
EV4.fit <- fitdist(Abfluss, "EV4", start=list(a=2700, v=2,k=2),
                   fix.arg = list(g=11151), method="mle")
```

The vector should be the **fix.arg** command inside the `fitdist` function.

As result I need the parameters a,v,k for every fixation value of the vector calculating by the fitdist function.

My idea was to build a `for` loop. But there are two problems.

1. How can I transfer the vector to the function? The `fitdist` function have to calculate the three parameters for every fixated value from the vector.
2. How could I store the results for the parameter-estimation in a matrix with four columns:

   i-th element of the vector,     a,      v,        k,?

My idea was something like this:

```
vector<-cumprod(c(11151, rep(1.01,100)))

for (i in 1:vector){
    EV4.fit <- fitdist(Abfluss, "EV4", start=list(a=2700, v=2,k=2),
                       **fix.arg = list(g=(i:vector)**, method="mle")
}
```

But this obviously don't work. I don't understand how can I say the function `fitdist`to calculate **automatically** the parameters for a every changing **fix.arg** inside the function?

Comment: Do you mean `for (vi in vector) { ... list(g=vi) ...}` ?

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. It seems to work but an error occurs: `Error in fitdist(Abfluss, "EV4", start = list(a = 2700, v = 2, k = 2),  : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 1`       Why you use the description `vi`instead of ì`?

Comment: If you want to index with `i` you have to do: `for (i in 1:length(vector)) { ... list(g=vector[i]) ... }` In you case it is possible to iterate directly over `vector` (`for (vi in vector) ...`)